# Función para juego de lucha

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en esta página, espero que me podáis ayudar
Estoy intentando hacer un "juego" que se pueda jugar en la terminal (lo típico de principiantes) en python, como soy nuevo en esto de programar y tal me he quedado atascado en una función de una pelea, donde quiero que si el personaje ataque a ese "monstruo" le quite la vida que le tiene que quitar ese arma, pero todo el rato me sale que le hago el mismo daño, y lo mismo si ese "monstruo" me ataca a mi.
Por aquí os dejo el código, gracias por vuestra atención!

````
    vidaEsqueleto = esqueleto.vida
    defensaEsquelto = random.randint(0,2)
    while esqueleto.vivo == True:
        print("Pegas el golple, y...")
        time.sleep(2)
        if defensaEsquelto == 0:
            print("Le aciertas el golpe al esqueleto, le queda", esqueleto.vida - espadaComun.daño, "de vida")
        if defensaEsquelto == 1:
            print("El esqueleto se defiende y no consigue devolverte el ataque")
        if defensaEsquelto == 2:
            print("El esqueleto se defiende y consigue devolverte el ataque, te queda", protagonista.vida - esqueleto.ataque, "de vida")
        break```
````

Comment: Fijate que defensaEsqueleto lo defines fuera el bucle por lo que elije un número, y se queda con este.

Comment: ...creo... no se si python funciona diferente.

Comment: Sí, tiene razon @ArnauCastellví! Si quiere que `defensaEsquelto` cambiar cada vez, tiene que ponerlo dentro el bucle. Tambíen parece que el buclo solo va a ejecutar una vez porque hay un `break`- no sé si le quiere asi o no.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene que cambiar la vida del personaje y el monstruo - en su código, solo escribe el resultado a la pantalla, nunca guardar para actualizar la vida del monstruo o la vida del personaje.

Por ejemplo, podrias usar `esqueleto.vida = esqueleto.vida - espadaComun.daño` despues de golpearla, y lo mismo para actualizar la vida de su personaje. Si usa eso puede cambiar su print a `print("Le aciertas el golpe al esqueleto, le queda", esqueleto.vida, "de vida")`.

Espero que ayudarle!